# Where would I find a copy of a US patent from 1905?

Tags: united-states, 1900s-decade

Attached is an image from the *Official Gazette of the United States Patent Office* from 1905. On the last line you can see patent 804,529 was issued to Minna B. Foster of Sausalito, CA on 14 Nov that year.

Google doesn't seem to be turning up the actual patent: Where would I go to find a copy?

[image: USPTO patent 804,529]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google actually have a special search engine for US patents at https://www.google.co.uk/advanced_patent_search but it doesn't seem to have much luck finding this one.

A bit of fiddling reveals that each patent has a URL based on it's number though, and I believe https://www.google.co.uk/patents/US804529 is what you're looking for:

> Be it known that I Minna B. Foster, a citizen of the United States,
>   residing at Sausalito, in the county of Marin and State of California,
>   have invented new and useful Improvements in Stock-Supporters, of
>   which the following is a specification.
>
> My invention relates to a device which is especially designed for
>   supporting stocks of soft material, such as are used by ladies for
>   neckwear.

and so on...

A PDF of the original can be [downloaded](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US804529.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Free Patents Online is another resource.  The patent you're looking for was the first match given by entering 804529 in the search field.  Images are available by clicking the "download PDF" link on http://www.freepatentsonline.com/0804529.html .

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are entirely correct, but since you already have the patent number, you can also just go straight to the source - the U.S. Patent Office! They have a bunch of different ways to search patents (see various options here: https://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/search-patents#heading-1), but the easiest in your case is to just go here: http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/patimg.htm

Then just enter the patent number and search. The patent by one M.B. Foster comes right up.